# elliptic curve $E:y^2＝x^3-x$ can be transformed to move the identity element to the origin

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, change-of-variable, arithmetic-geometry, formal-groups

For example, elliptic curve $E:y^2＝x^3-x$ can be transformed
to move the identity element to the origin, $(z,w)=(0,0)$, we do the change of coordinates $z=-x/y$, $w=-1/y$. The equation of this curve then becomes
$w=z^3+zw^2\quad$

We often make this transformation to figure out formal group associated to elliptic curve.

But what do we do when $y＝0$?

I'm confused.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier if you write in projective coordinates. Let $E$ be given as
$$Y^2Z = X^3 -XZ^2$$
then the rational map $(x,y) \mapsto (-x/y, -1/y)$ on the affine chart where $Z = 1$ can be extended to a morphism on the projective closure ($E$ above) by
$$(X : Y:Z) \mapsto (-X: -Z : Y)$$

In particular $(0:0:1)$ maps to $(0:1:0)$ - the point at infinity on your curve. This may also be seen in an analagous way to complex analysis by looking at the order of the poles of the functions $-x/y$ and $-1/y$ at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for elaborate answer.Could I ask some tiny questions? How can I check （x,y）→（-x/y,-1/y） extended to （X:Y:Z）→（-X:-Z:Y）？

Comment: Set $x = X/Z$ and $y = Y/Z$ then multiply through by $Y$.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still confused about the notation like '$-x/y$'. Why do we not consider the situation $y＝0$? Because $y$ is function like elliptic function? But now, y is just an element of  given field. I'm so confused.

Comment: Answering that question is probably going to take more than a comment. The $x$ and $y$ are elements of the function field $K(E)$, which is the fraction field of the quotient ring $K[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3 - Ax - B)$ (in fact choose any affine patch). Giving a rational map from $E$ to a projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ is just given by $f_0, ..., f_n \in K(E)$. At any point of $E$ you can "evaluate" $f_i$ just by "plugging in" the value of $x,y$ at the point. But since $E$ is projective we can often resolve indeterminacy (places where the map looks badly behaved) in the way I mention in my answer.

Comment: 1.Could you tell me how can I restrict map to affine chart? That is, we define binational map from $E$ to $E':XZ^2＝X^3＋XY^2$ by $[X:Y:Z] to [X:Z:-Y]$, then, How can I show that affine chart $Z＝1$ of $E$ to the affine chart with $Y＝-1$? The result must be $（x,y）to （-y/x,-1/y）$, but How can I deduce that?  Thank you for your help. Thank you.

Comment: 2. $E$ and $E'$ is birational because the map $φ：[X:Y:Z] to [X:Z:-Y] $ is rational and it is obvious it has inverse rational map. And the binational map φ is isogeny between elliptic curves （because it sends $[0:1:0] $ to $[0:0:1]$）, so we can say φ is not merely  binational but also group isomorphism from $E$ to $E'$, so we can say $E'$ inherits the elliptic curveness（genus 1, smooth, has base point ）and  arithmetic group law. Is this sentence all correct ? Thank you for your correction.

Comment: Sorry, for the 1st comment, $（x,y） to （-x/y,-1/y）$ is correct.